# datetime format in matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have some data that was given to me in excel and the time format is rather confusing. The fist column of the is the DateTime but with incorrect HH:MM and the second column is the correct hour of the day HH:MM:

```
time = {'01/01/2000 00:00',num2str(2300);
    '01/01/2000 00:00',num2str(2400);
    '01/01/2000 00:00',num2str(10);
    '01/01/2000 00:00',num2str(100)};
```

However, when the time exceeds midnight, instead of being 00:10 the time is 10, and 01:00 is 100. How could I alter these to the correct format? i.e. from the example above I would like the outcome to be:

```
time = {'01/01/2000 23:00';
    '01/01/2000 24:00';
    '01/01/2000 00:10';
    '01/01/2000 01:00'};
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: i would `sprintf` the second column using the width specifier, which would prepend any missing Zeros, then insert a colon after the second character

Comment: then of course `strcat` your two columns

Comment: To clarify AK4749's suggestion: Instead of `num2str(time)`, try `sprintf('%02i:%02i', hours, minutes)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) in MATLAB, you can use the field width specifier:

[image: sprintf arguments]

where

> Field width:
>   Minimum number of characters to print. Can be a number, or an asterisk (*) to refer to an argument in the input list. For example, the input list ('%12d', intmax) is equivalent to ('%*d', 12, intmax).

Thus your times should end up all looking like "XX:XX", with the leading zero added by the sprintf if it is missing and the colon added in.

Thanks to @Junuxx for the exact command: `sprintf('%02i:%02i', hours, minutes)`

To separate hours and minutes, you would obviously do time % 100 to get the minutes and integer divide by 100 to get the hours.

From there, you simply `strcat` or concatenate `["a" "b"]` your two columns to get your desired result.